# Conversion of NSString to NSDate in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert @"4:30 PM" (string) to NSDate format. I am unable to do this and I am getting unexpected out put.

My code

```
var strDate = "4:30 PM"
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(strDate)
print(date)
```

OutPut : Optional(2000-01-01 11:00:00 +0000)

Comment: What's your current timeZone ? Difference of 5:50 (India?) What are you expecting?

Comment: the variable strDate is too abstract. I think you should give a more specific strDate

Comment: Yup its India but while debugging am able to see UTC. Am not clear regarding this. @Larme

Comment: Actually its my requirement :( @jinhua liao

Comment: If you set your timezone to `IST (India Standard Time)` you should get your expected output. `dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "IST")`

Comment: Am unable to get expected output @sbarow

Comment: What is your expected output? `Optional(2000-01-01 16:30:00 +0000)`

Comment: @Larme Its 5:30 ... @-MyiOS there is nothing new with **Swift** here and it will give you same output in **Objective-C**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove optional, define your `date` constant as:

```
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(strDate) as NSDate!
```

To calculate time in your local time zone, add

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name:"UTC")
```

In summary, here is what you want:

```
var strDate = "4:30 PM"
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name:"UTC")
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(strDate) as NSDate!
print(date)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `NSDateFormatter` will return an optional `NSDate` because maybe it won't be able to parse your input.
2. `NSDateFormatter` will also return an `NSDate` object which only store a raw date (so it's in GMT timezone), but printing it will localize the output. For example in France I am in GMT+1 timezone so the output will always be one hour more than what I entered in strDate.

Comment: Do i need to Add or subtract from the output according to my time zone. @Fantattitude